# Error 'string' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

estoy aprendiendo a usar C++, estoy trabajando en un programa y para ello necesito una matriz de strings, pero me marca el error 'string' was not declared in this scope, ¿alguna sugerencia?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nodos=0, grupos=0;
    printf("Calculadora de armaduras en 2 dimensiones\n");
    scanf("¿Cuántos nodos tiene su estructura?\nNodos: %lf", &nodos);
    printf("\nA continuación se le pedirá que agrupe sus nodos en grupos de 3, de acuerdo a cuáles están unidos entre sí, nombre sus nodos con las letras del abecedario\n");
    scanf("\n¿Cuántos grupos contiene su armadura?\nGrupos: %lf", &grupos);
    string matrizG[grupos][3];
    for(int i=1; i<=grupos; i=i+1){
         n to_string(int i);
        scanf("Grupo " + n + "\nPunto 1: %lf Punto 2: %lf Punto 3: %lf", matrizG[i][1], matrizG[i][2], matrizG[i][3]);
    }
    printf(matrizG);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debe ser String?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que incluir la librería

```
#include <string>
```

Es en esta librería donde se encuentra la clase `std::string`.

Por otro lado, el primer elemento de un array es **siempre** el 0, luego si defines un array de tres posiciones:

```
string matrizG[grupos][3];
```

Las mismas serán accesibles con los índices 0 a 2 ... tu lo estás haciendo con los índices 1 a 3:

```
scanf("Grupo " + n + "\nPunto 1: %lf Punto 2: %lf Punto 3: %lf",
      matrizG[i][1],  matrizG[i][2], matrizG[i][3]);
```

Y ya que estás en C++, reemplaza `cstdio` por `iostream`, `printf` por `cout` y `scanf` por `cin`:

```
cout >> "Calculadora de armaduras en 2 dimensiones\n"
     >> "¿Cuántos nodos tiene su estructura?\n"
     >> "Nodos: ";
cin >> nodos;

cout << "\nA continuación se le pedirá que agrupe sus nodos en grupos de 3,"
     << "de acuerdo a cuáles están unidos entre sí, nombre sus nodos con "
     << "las letras del abecedario\n"
     << "\n¿Cuántos grupos contiene su armadura?\n"
     << "Grupos: ";
cin >> grupos;
```

y por otro lado

```
cout << "Grupo " << n << "\n";

for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    cout << "Punto " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> matriz[i][j];
}
```

Finalmente, **no puedes** imprimir un array así:

```
printf(matrizG);
```

Por varias razones:

- `printf` es una función heredada de C. Es, por tanto, una función muy simple y solo sabe imprimir tipos básicos
- Consecuencia del punto anterior, no sabe tratar objetos propios de C++ (como `std::string`)
- En cuanto le pasas el array a la función, el array se convierte en un puntero y pierdes cualquier referencia al tamaño del mismo. Es decir, sin pasar de forma expresa (algo que no puedes) el tamaño del array, la función no será capaz de imprimir dicho array.

Para imprimir el array debes recorrerlo e ir imprimiendo sus elementos:

```
for(int i=0; i<grupos; i++)
{
    cout << "Grupo " << i+1 << '\n';
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        cout << "  " << matriz[i][j] << ' ';
    cout << '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: Ya que no se menciona, como sustituto a `system("pause")` puedes usar `cin.get()`.